# @Delete and @MoveFrom in one request

Tags: java, aem, sling

I'm trying to implement a carousel with html5smartimage widget working within a multifield xtype. Let me describe how it works.
The data structure is as follows:

```
\carousel
 \slides
  \1
   |image1
   |image2
   |...
  \2
   |...
```

In html5smartimage, two requests are actually made to save the image. The first one uploads the file with *.sftmp extension to a temporary path (carousel-temp/slides/1/image1) and later, when you click OK in the dialog, the second request is issued, and it contains the following postData:

```
./sling:resourceType:project1/components/carousel
./jcr:lastModified:
./jcr:lastModifiedBy:
_charset_:utf-8
:status:browser
./slides@Delete:
:assetname:
./slides/1/image1/fileReference:
./slides/1/image1/file@MoveFrom:/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel_temp/slides/1/image1/file.sftmp
./slides/1/image1/imageMap:
./slides/1/image1/imageCrop:
./slides/1/image1/imageRotate:0
:assetname:
./slides/1/image2/fileReference:
./slides/1/jcr:lastModified:
./slides/1/jcr:lastModifiedBy:
./slides/1/image2/imageMap:
./slides/1/image2/imageCrop:
./slides/1/image2/imageRotate:0
./slides/1/image1/sling:resourceType:foundation/components/image
./slides/1/image2/sling:resourceType:foundation/components/image
:cq:undoblobs:update:/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/./slides/1/image1/slides/1/image1
:cq:undoblobs:update:/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/./slides/1/image2/slides/1/image2
```

As a result of this request, it looks like @moveFrom moves the image from temporary path to the image1/file node, but then the parent of destination node gets removed by ./slides@Delete instruction. My theory gets confirmed by the changelog returned by Sling:

```
moved("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image1/file.sftmp", "/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image1/file");
deleted("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/sling:resourceType");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/jcr:lastModified");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/jcr:lastModifiedBy");
created("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides");
created("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1");
created("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image1");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image1/imageRotate");
created("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image2");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/jcr:lastModified");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/jcr:lastModifiedBy");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image2/imageRotate");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image1/sling:resourceType");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/content-carousel/carousel/slides/1/image2/sling:resourceType");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/cq:lastModified");
modified("/content/project1/en_GB/jcr:content/cq:lastModifiedBy")
```

Is there a way to change priority of @Delete and @moveFrom suffixes to avoid y problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also post the XML of your dialog? If I understand you right, you are trying to have a mutlifield widget with html5smartimage as its configured type? I am quite shure this won't work. I would try a multi component aproach: Carousel component with some basic settings, containing a parsys for the authors where you can only add image components.

Comment: We discussed using parsys for that, but decided to go with smartimage. I've found a lib here: http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2014/04/aem-cq-56-slide-show-component.html, but it contains a lot of hacks but still doesn't work :)

Comment: You can still use smartimage, but within the subcomponent...